# Ajuda Sintx error

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber onde se encontra meu erro nesta classe em `php`, se alguém puder ajudar agradeço, o erro é o seguinte:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_POST' (T_VARIABLE) in
>   C:\wamp\www\exercicio1\classe\function.class.php on line 4

```
class Pessoa{

    var $codigo = $_POST["codigo"];
    var $nome = $_POST["nome"];
    var $altura = $_POST["altura"];
    var $idade = $_POST["idade"];
    var $dt_nasc = $_POST["dt_nasc"];
    var $escol = $_POST["escol"];
    var $salario = $_POST["salario"];

    function crescer($centimetros){
    $this->altura+=$centimetros;

    }

    function formar($titulo){
    &this->idade+=$anos;



    }

    function envelhecer($anos){
    $this->idade+=$anos;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

O erro esta no `$_POST`, não é possível iniciar valores dos atributos da classe desse jeito.

O ideia é você criar um construtor recebendo o parâmetro.

```
class Pessoa{

    var $codigo;
    var $nome;
    var $altura;
    var $idade;
    var $dt_nasc;
    var $escol;
    var $salario;

    function __construct($POST){
        $this->codigo = $POST['codigo'];
        //.. aqui você inicializa todos os parametros
    }

    function crescer($centimetros){
        $this->altura+=$centimetros;
    }

    function formar($titulo){
        $this->idade+=$anos;
    }

    function envelhecer($anos){
        $this->idade+=$anos;
    }

}

$Pessoa = new Pessoa($_POST);
```

E na linha `&this->idade+=$anos;` em vez de `$` você colocou `&`

Answer (score 0):

Você não pode fazer esse tipo inicialização na propriedes, se precisar definir uma valor padrão dinamico faço no construtor.

Substitua o `var` que era usado no php4 por uma das tres visibilidade disponivel, `public`, `protected` e `private`.

```
class Pessoa{

public function __construct($info){
    $this->codigo = $info["codigo"];
    $this->nome = $info["nome"];
    $this->altura = $info["altura"];
    $this->idade = $info["idade"];
    $this->dt_nasc = $info["dt_nasc"];
    $this->escol = $info["escol"];
    $this->salario = $info["salario"];
}

//demais métodos.
```

[Manual - visibilidade](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)